# Flask Python: Accept data from Ionic app into flask

Tags: python, mysql, ionic-framework, flask

I created an API that can get data from MySQL. It working if the stockList is defined. However, in actual world, I need to get it from the Ionic app, and the stockList is defined by individual user.

Simply put `stockList =[]` does not work.
Currently the flask_app.py is as below:

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,abort,make_response,request
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/KLSEwatch', methods=['GET'])
def KLSEwatch():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='vinvin.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',user='vinvin',passwd='xxx',db='vinukdb$default',cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    curs = db.cursor()
    stockList = ['SHELL','GENM']
    placeholders = ','.join(['%s'] * len(stockList))
    query = 'SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock IN ({})'.format(placeholders)
    curs.execute(query,tuple(stockList))
    f = curs.fetchall()
    return jsonify({'Stock': f})
```

what I shall replace stockList as it shall get the data from user, which is from an Ionic app. The data is can be string or a 4 digits numbers

Below is the code in watchlistCtrl.js in Ionic app

```
    //setting get counter-number of get requests-
    var getCounter = 0;
    for (var market in watchListQuery) {
      if(watchListQuery[market].length>0){
        getCounter += 1;
      }
    }
    if(getCounter == 0)
      $ionicLoading.hide();


    $scope.watchedStocks = [];
    for (var market in watchListQuery) {
      if(watchListQuery[market].length>0){
        var queryString = watchListQuery[market].toString().replace(/,/g, "','");

        $webServicesFactory.get($marketProvider[market].queryURL+"/watchlist_query", {AnonymousToken: $marketProvider[market].token}, {parameters:{stockList:queryString}}).then(
          function success(data) {
            getCounter -=1 ;

            $scope.watchedStocks = $scope.watchedStocks.concat(data);
            if(getCounter <= 0)
              $ionicLoading.hide();
          },
          function error() {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
          }
        );
      }
    }//end of for each loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show us any of your Ionic code, but here's a simple example of taking input from your Ionic app and submitting it to Flask. First, some HTML for the frontend (I'm only using Angular, since that is the common theme here - the rest of Ionic isn't relevant to this problem):

```
<!-- templates/home.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Ionic / Flask</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>Enter a comma-separated string value, like "BAC,XYZ"</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="stockList">
    <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.14/angular.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function ($http, $log, $scope) {
      $scope.stockList = '';
      $scope.submit = function () {
        $http.get('/KLSEwatch', {params: {stockList: $scope.stockList}}).then(function (result) {
          $log.log('This is the query to execute: ',result.data)
        })
      };
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And then here's a modified version of your Flask app, to demonstrate that this will generate the correct query:

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask,jsonify,abort,make_response,request, render_template
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/KLSEwatch', methods=['GET'])
def KLSEwatch():
    stockList = request.args['stockList'].split(',')
    placeholders = ','.join(['%s'] * len(stockList))
    query = 'SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock IN ({})'.format(placeholders)
    print('This is the query: %s' % (query % tuple(stockList)))
    return query % tuple(stockList)

app.run()
```

All you need to do is run the app, enter a string value into the input field & submit it, and then check the results in your browser console log, or in the output for the Flask app.

Comment: what is the '@pp.route('/')' which 'return render_template('home.html')' do?

Comment: I add the Ionic code part it is in the watchlistCtrl.js